# How to dynamically add new user to mysql with php?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

How can I add a new user to a db on the fly using php? I understand how to add accounts with the root account in terminal and through php. I'm not sure how to form a dbhandle when `mysql_connect(hostname, username, password)` doesn't have a username or password to use. Should a guest account be made for this purpose? However, it seems like a bad idea to store the guest or root login info in a session variable for every user that doesn't have an account yet. I've read a few forums that mention a verification step occurring after the information has been submitted and that is when the account is created. A simple page diagram (page1 -> page2) for the proper steps would be much appreciated!

Comment: Accessing your database requires in fact an administrator mysql account that should be different from the app account associated with their mysql database account.

Comment: You seem to be confusing end users with the service account you use to connect your application to the database and the admin account you use to manage your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These username and password are the mysql server's username and password and not a user specific details that are in your application.
Read more here how to use mysql connection via php : https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp